# Assign Json to a string without serilization in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, deserialization

I have a JSON string

```
{
  "F1":
  { 
    "BF1":"BV1",
    "BF2":"BV2"
  },
  "F2":"BF1"
}
```

and I wish to assign it to an object of this type

```
public class MyType
{
   public string F1 {get;set;} 
   public string F2 {get;set;}
}
```

in other words, I need to convert JSON to an object, but the inner object is to be assigned as a JSON string

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work out?

Comment: Sounds like you'll probably need a custom converter. We can't easily provide a useful example of that without knowing at least which JSON framework you're using, e.g. Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json.

Comment: The easiest way is to deserialize the whole thing and re-serialize the part that you want to stay JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simpliest way is

```
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

    MyType myType = new MyType
    {
        F1 = jObj["F1"].ToString(),
        F2 = jObj["F2"].ToString()
    };
```

or if you don't want indented formating

```
MyType myType = new MyType
    {
        F1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObj["F1"]),
        F2 = (string) jObj["F2"];
    };
```

of if you like a hard way

```
MyType myType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json,new MyTypeJsonConverter());

public class MyTypeJsonConverter : JsonConverter<MyType>
{
    public override MyType ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, MyType existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);

        return new MyType
        {
            F1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObj["F1"]),
            F2 = (string)jObj["F2"]
        };
    }

    // or maybe this 
    // public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, MyType value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var val = new
        {
            F1 = JObject.Parse(value.F1),
            F2 = value.F2
        };
        
        writer.WriteRaw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(val, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
    }
    
}
```

or if you have many properties that should deserialize common way

```
MyType myType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json);

public class MyType
{ 
   [JsonConverter(typeof(MyTypePropertyJsonConverter))]
    public string F1 { get; set; }
    
    public string F2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyTypePropertyJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, string existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JToken.Load(reader));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but in the class MyTypePropertyJsonConverter how to code WriteJson Method??

Comment: @TahaBabi Which code are you using?

Comment: i am using the fourth

Comment: @TahaBabi  I fixed it , try now

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer posted by @serge looks best to me. But I spent some time to resolve your issue and I ended up with the below code:

```
dynamic jsonElement = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
MyType myType = new MyType();
myType.F1 = jsonElement.GetProperty("F1").ToString();
myType.F2 = jsonElement.GetProperty("F2").ToString();       
Console.WriteLine(myType.F1 + ", " + myType.F2);
```

I hope it may help you some way.